# Dependency Injections with Mutable Objects

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

Would it be a bad idea to pass anything that could possibly not work in the future to a class?

For instance, passing a database connection (or anything that can possibly have it's methods rendered useless) to multiple classes? With JavaScript, these are passed by reference, therefore if  the database connection is canceled outside of the class, the object within the classes wouldn't work? Now would this be bad, seeing now that all the models and things which use the database in methods will not work (without any notice that all the classes using the object now cannot be used).

Comment: don't inject points of failure or more custom work for the "class" to perform, inject capabilities that usefully handle problems themselves.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the advice. How would I go about injecting a database? EDIT: USING a database in a model.

Comment: you don't inject a db, that's introducing way too many failure points, and jumbling up your concerns. if you use raw DB stuff in your class, you will probably find yourself repeating code a lot. you need a method that calls the database and returns data or an error to the caller. in your class, you then need to handle both errors and data.

Comment: @dandavis what is this mystical database caller called? dependency injection container? Are there any articles I could read? And can you post an answer so I can accept! :D

Comment: You control the code so don't close the database connection - in programming there's a ton of stuff that can break if you do "x" - I don't see a problem with passing in a connection or an object that wraps around a connection.

Comment: @MartinKonecny I see this question may be more opinion based than I realized.

Comment: So back to the question, is it a bad idea?

Comment: This comes down to *Dependency Lifetimes*. Lifetime management is part of a DI/IoC framework. It makes to sense to access an object after it is "closed/disposed", and one pattern to decrease scope is to employ a Unit Of Work pattern - the connection/transaction is created (possible with pooling), used, and then the work ends thereby no longer maintaining a dependency. Likewise, mutating shared objects can be problematic - but this needs to be worked out in the semantic usage patterns.

Comment: @user2864740 That seems quite difficult, I think I'm just going to restructure my code.

Comment: I outline some possible remedies for this situation in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884474/how-do-you-avoid-injecting-global-state-when-sharing-dependencies-in-di

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database connection is a perfect example of something to pass into a class for dependency injection.

Dependency injection is useful for testing your models/classes, and during testing you want to "mock" certain services such as your database. In your tests, instead of "injecting" a database object, you would "inject" a mock object that models your database functionality.

Comment: so make a mock object which gets data from the database or do you mean use a dependency injection of the database alone. If it's a mock object which gets data from the database, what if I have multiple mock objects to the same database, do I instantiate a new database in each?

Comment: A mock object could be something that simulates your database, but is not your database. For example, you might hard code a list of rows to be returned for a certain query.

Comment: This would be the case where you're eliminating your database from testing logic, you are instead testing the code of the class/model you are injecting into.

Comment: okay, and ideally all the connections to the database should be handled within that object.

Comment: Yes, you want to abstract the database away in the object, so it can be replaced with a mock object.

Comment: I'd argue that injecting a shared mutable object does not respect the principle of least authority: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege