# How do you avoid injecting global state when sharing dependencies in DI?

Tags: dependency-injection, global-variables, state

Imagine you inject a single database connection to a handful of service classes. They now share what's essentially a global mutable state. How do DI frameworks deal with this? Do they:

- Freeze the dependency before injection?
- Only share immutable objects?
- Wrap each dependency in a decorator to only provide exactly what's dependent on?

I tried searching for this and am a bit surprised I didn't find much. Feel free to provide links.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Comment: Possible duplicate (old): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252904/dependency-injections-with-mutable-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DI containers provide the feature of registering a dependency within a Lifetime. For instance in .net core DI you can register a service with three different lifetimes:

- Singleton: There is only one single instance. All the consumers of that service will use that instance. If one consumer changes the state of that dependency, all the other consumers will see that change.
- Scoped: There is one instance per scope, where a scope is a web request. If a consumer changes the state of a scoped service, all the other consumers that will run in the same web request will see the change.
- Transient: Each consumer uses a different instance of the service.

Always in .net core, the DBContext is (by default) added as a scoped service, this means that in the same web request all the consumers will use the same instance and this is useful when you need to run a transaction across different consumers (or better across different repositories).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Aren't alternative 1 and 2 both sharing mutable state? So it's not really a solution?

Comment: What do you want to avoid, exactly? With DI you don't have a Global Mutable State, each class has it's own dependencies. It's normal that two classes share the same instance for a given dependency, think about a producer and a consumer who share a buffer. Moreover when using DI you can easily design tests and mock dependencies, which you cannot do when using global access objects. Is there any specific behaviour or side effect that worries you?

Comment: I don't care if it's "normal", I still consider it equivalent to global mutable state, and a bug in the DI pattern that should be fixed. But yes, of course DI is better, just not as good as it can and should be. :)

Comment: You can avoid the mutal state by injecting Transient dependencies. When you use Scoped and Singleton dependencies is because *you want to* share the state. One example is that you want to begin a transaction at the service layer and then to use the same transaction in your repositories to handle the data layer. Of course adding a Singleton dependency should be done when you really need a singleton: it is not a problem with the DI, it is a problem with who is designing the dependencies lifetime. DI just does not limit the developers.

Comment: OK, so what I'm looking for is probably a DI framework that makes sure shared state is immutable.